# Do Frames Have Separate Frame Positions In Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, layout, tkinter

I've ran into a problem, that I thought I knew the answer to. It's very strange, I made a frame to put in entries and buttons, so that they would not appear far apart due to a box I have made. But the entries and buttons are not in the frame because the background of the frame is red but no red is anywhere, and the entries/buttons are still separated strangely.

The Code:

```
# Hex GUI
import re
import tkinter as tk

hexa_checker_regex = re.compile(r'^#')


class Window:


    def __init__(self, master, error_checker):
        self.error_checker = error_checker
        self.master = master
        self.master.configure(bg='LightBlue')
        self.set_up()


    def set_up(self):

        # =====FRAME FOR ENTRYS + BUTTONS=====

        self.enter_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, bg='Red').grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='n')

        # =====COLOR BOX=====

        self.color = tk.Frame(self.master, highlightbackground='Black', height=100, width=100, highlightthickness=5)
        self.color.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # =====SEPERATOR=====

        tk.Frame(self.master, width=200, bg='LightBlue').grid(row=0, column=1)


        # =====HEXADECIMAL COLORS=====

        tk.Label(self.enter_frame, text='Hex:', bg='LightBlue').grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='n')

        self.the_color_hex = tk.Entry(self.enter_frame, width=50)
        self.the_color_hex.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='n')

        tk.Button(self.enter_frame, text='Change Color', command=self.change_color_hex).grid(row=0, column=4, sticky='n')

        # =====HEX ERROR=====

        tk.Label(self.enter_frame, textvariable=self.error_checker, bg='LightBlue').grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky='n')

        # =====REGULAR COLORS===== <--- UNFINISHED RAN INTO ERROR FIRST

        tk.Label(self.enter_frame, text='Color:', bg='LightBlue').grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='n')

        self.reg_color = tk.Entry(self.enter_frame, width=50)
        self.reg_color.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky='n')



    def change_color_hex(self):
        if hexa_checker_regex.search(self.the_color_hex.get()) is None:
            self.error_checker.set('That is an invalid hexadecimal value!')
        else:
            try:
                self.color.configure(bg=self.the_color.get())
                self.error_checker.set('')
            except:
                self.error_checker.set('That is an invalid hexadecimal value!')
        self.the_color_hex.delete(0, 'end')



root = tk.Tk()
error_checker = tk.StringVar()
app = Window(root, error_checker)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Looks Like]

So, why are the entries and buttons not in the frame. Also, why would the position of the entries and buttons be affected by the box if they are in the frame (which they aren't because the background of the frame is red)?

Comment: I'm not certain, but just try defining your frame and then packing it into the grid on a seperate line. I've had problems in the past because of defining and applying the grid method on the same line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
self.enter_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, bg='Red').grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='n')
```

self.enter_frame will be equal to 'None' so tkinter then can't use this to place the other widgets. Change this to

```
 self.enter_frame = tk.Frame(self.master, bg='Red')
 self.enter_frame.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='n')
```

and some of your problems will disappear.

Another error is this line

```
self.color.configure(bg=self.the_color.get())
```

It should be

```
self.color.configure(bg=self.the_color_hex.get())
```